# If || . || is a norm over a field, then there exists $\delta$ > 0 such that ||x|| = $\delta$ |x|, where |x| is the absolute value of x.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

My approach is to first show that $||x||\le\delta|x|$ and then $||x||\ge\delta|x|$

I have taken the first part to be trivial. How do I prove the other part? Or should I use a different approach?

Comment: What exactly is a "norm over a field"? In my experience, the norm over the field is usually just the modulus/absolute value (which would just give $\delta = 1$...), at least for the fields $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$.

Comment: The trivial norm ($\phi(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $\phi(x)=1$ if $x\neq 0$) is a counterexample.  It satisfies all defining properties of a norm on a field: $\phi(x)\geq 0$ with equality iff $x=0$, $\phi(x+y)\leq\phi(x)+\phi(y)$, and $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer the norm here can be either the modulus norm, or supremum norm, or any other norm. That has not been distinguished. So we have to assume it can be any norm over the field.

Comment: I guess the field in question should be either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and it is a norm in the sense of normed spaces, i.e. $\|x\|=0$ iff $x=0$, $\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|x\|$ and $\|x+y\|\leq\|x\|+\|y\|$?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to show that if you have the field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and consider it as a normed vector space of dimension one over itself, than the given norm is just a multiple of the absolute value. So I will prove this.

Let $\delta = \|1\|$. We will show that this is the sought constant. Indeed, take any $x$ in the field. As $x$ is also a scalar, we can factor it out from the norm:
$$\|x\| = \|x \cdot 1\| = |x| \: \|1\| = \delta \|x\|.$$

Hence, $\|x\| = \delta |x|$ and we are done.